# Touchpad auto-clicking on stuff while browsing

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, touchpad

I have a new Asus a55vd computer with Windows 7.

I noticed something very annoying... while browsing in chrome quite frequently when opening a new page and moving the cursor around at the same time while it's still loading, the stuff gets clicked on ... so that something else opens instead - some further link on the site :(((

I installed new touchpad drivers and disabled most of the gestures on the touchpad (for example touch drag), but it didn't help. Also sometimes when moving cursor around the text on the page gets selected.

Comment: How are you moving the cursor around while pages are loading?  With your finger or stylus, you're dragging?  Because typically touchpad interfaces respond to touching links as clicking them.  Doesn't the cursor just move instantly when you touch somewhere?  Why would you be dragging it around in the first place?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special... just moving cursor in anticipation where I want to click next maybe... not even sure.. I just know that this behaviour is not normal and on my Mac it doesn't happen. Not sure what you mean by "touchpad interfaces respond to touching links as clicking them"..

Comment: On my smartphone, if I touch a link, its going to open regardless of whether I'm dragging or not. Touch a link = click a link. Why are you dragging a cursor around on a touch surface?  It should just hop to where ever you touch instantly, no dragging necessary.  When you touch a link, its going to open, thats how touchpad software was written. I don't know, but there _may_ be an option to ignore links while dragging...

Comment: I'm not dragging.... I just disabled the "touch drag" feature which I thought my be interfering and causing the problem I experience. PS: why you mention smartphone? I have problems on the computer.

Comment: my bad, I was under the impression you were on a tablet. Ok so you've disbaled _most_ of the touch gestures, does the problem remain when you disable _all_ of the gestures?  Can you plug in a mouse and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: with the mouse it doesn't.. but I can't be sure because this happens 'rarely' and I haven't used it with a mouse for that long... I disabled zoom, rotate, all three-finger gestures... I think the problem would probably go away if I disabled tap-to-click but I don't want to do that because this is essential.

Comment: Rarely? well in your original post you said it happens 'quite frequently.'  Anyway it sounds to me like the touchpad is just sensitive to pressure, which probably varies randomly as you move the cursor around waiting for pages to load, resulting in what seems like spontaneous clicks or highlights.

Comment: Yes, quite frequently - it means that it bothers me a lot.. but 'rarely' enough that I cannot test if the problem is still present just like this.. sometimes it happens twice in 10 minutes other times it doesn't happen for a few hours. Touchpad being too sensitive? Maybe but I think it's some glitch in the software when it thinks there was a tap when there wasn't.

Comment: A glitch in the software is highly unlikely.  Touchpads are ancient technology whos bugs were sorted out years ago.  If it were the software, there would probably be a lot more people registering complaints and it'd be easy to find via google.  It seems to me like it registers "false clicks" not as a random glitch, but as a variation in the pressure on the pad as you move it around.  Toggling the "tap-to-click" on and off will confirm if this is the issue.  I can register tap to clicks on a touchpad simply by applying more pressure, without ever lifting off the pad at all.

Comment: These kind of touchpads are not ancient technology, not this one on Asus that tries to mimick Apple ones... they are more complex than normal ancient ones. And it probably is a software bug because it cannot be anything else... Hardware is not at fault because then it would happen more frequently (all the time), it's in the logic. Hardware just senses the presence of the finger and the software calculates what fingers are doing at the moment. Now it happened after using that computer for 2 minutes and I really really hate it :(

Comment: I uninstalled Elantech drivers so it disabled all the special gestures... only Windows drivers are running the touchpad now... it still sucks... it's selecting and clicking on things. Crap. So maybe it is some hardware logic after all... not the hardware itself but some programmable chips in there. I read on the web that Elantech is not that good, Synaptics is much better. What can I do?! If I don't solve this, this laptop is useless... and it's such a good laptop in all the other regards. CRAP

Comment: ehhh... I wasn't implying hardware problem, but user error.